# Does deleting desktop environment(Unity) also remove core application such as file manager and other tools like calenders e.t.c?

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-environments

Linux beginner here.

Different desktop environments have different core applications and tools which are part of it. Some applications also come by default such as Firefox or VLC in different distro. So, would those applications and tools gonna get deleted if desktop environment is removed?

Comment: Short answer is yes, it removes those apps that are dependencies for `ubuntu-desktop` meta package.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how you find out by using `apt-get`/`apt`/`aptitude`. If you use one of these tools to remove Unity, then the tool will tell you which applications depend on Unity when removing it and (in the case of `apt-get`/`apt`/`aptitude` in command line mode) will prompt you with the list of packages that it would remove. `aptitude` in curses mode will show you the a similar list, when you press `g` for go (and you can still abort).

On seeing the list, you should be able to decide whether you do or do not want to have those applications be removed because they depend on Unity.